# AWS Eventbridge Name param

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-event-bridge

I'm implementing a AWS v3 event bridge from inside a Typescript application we have, using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge however when I run this code:

```
import { EventBridgeClient, ActivateEventSourceCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge";

const client = new EventBridgeClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

// this is the BODY section of what is sent
const dataToSend = {
  email_address: user_email,
  status: action,
  merge_fields: {
        FNAME: user_givenName,
        LNAME: user_familyName,
  },
  interests: interestId,
};

const entry = {
  Entries: [
    {
      EventBusName: "Subscriptions",
      Source: "custom.subscriptions",
      DetailType: "subscription",
      Detail: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    },
  ],
};

const params = {
  Name: "TestBus",
  Description: "data bus",
  Entry: JSON.stringify(entry),
};

const command = new ActivateEventSourceCommand(params);

try {
  const data = await client.send(command);
  // process data.
  console.log("data>>", data);
} catch (error) {
  // error handling.
  console.log("err>>", error);
}
```

I get the error:

**err>> ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'TestBus' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: aws.partner(/[.-_A-Za-z0-9]+){2,}**

Running the regex through this site: https://www.regextester.com/ it's shown as the forward slash is invalid.

Looking through the supplied code, I can see the 'Name' parameter should be a string, and other examples I've viewed have a similar name to the one I am using. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Running the regex through this site: https://www.regextester.com/ shows it as invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I had two issues in there:

```
EventBusName: "Subscriptions",
```

should be:

```
EventBusName: "default",
```

(or create the new EventBus, with the name supplied) and `ActivateEventSourceCommand` should be `PutEventsCommand` removing the `params` const and with the command as:

```
const command = new PutEventsCommand(entry);
```

[edit]
Also opened this as a Github bug and received this reply: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2804 - hope that helps someone in the future!!